# How to plot a complete graph in R?

Tags: r, graph

I want to plot complete graphs in R.

How can I do that? I found only one package on CRAN that does have a function to generate complete graphs. But this package, namely "RnavGraph", didn't install but exited with error status. Searching further seems to be difficult, because of the different meanings of graph, which is not soley associated with graph structures but also with plots.

*How can I plot a [complete graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) in R?*

Ps:
But I got the following error when I tried to install "RnavGraph":

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘graph’, ‘RBGL’ are not available for package ‘RnavGraph’
* removing ‘/home/steve/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RnavGraph’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpIW4p30/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RnavGraph") :
  installation of package ‘RnavGraph’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R");
biocLite("graph");
biocLite("RBGL")` and then try loading `RnavGraph` again

Comment: This works! But then I cannot yet plot the graph, as this needs Rgraphviz and I get the issue "package ‘Rgraphviz’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)". I rather not update R, as at this point I cannot do it with the package manager, and I don't want to install it from source. Is there another option to plot a complete graph?

Comment: @David Arenburg a big thanks for helping to find a solution!

Comment: Np, doesn't look it helped you in any way

Comment: I think you can do this using the `randomGraph` function from the `graph` package. For example, for 5 nodes, `g <- randomGraph(1:5, 1,1); plot(g)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `igraph`. Here's a simple way:

```
library(igraph)

CompleteGraph <- function(n) {
  myEdges <- combn(1:n,2)
  myGraph <- graph(myEdges, directed=FALSE)
  return(myGraph)
}

myGraph <- CompleteGraph(10)

plot(myGraph)
```

The `igraph` package lets you make a graph from a list of edges. In this case, I used `combn` to generate all unique combinations of two numbers from the vector `1:n`. When I feed this into the `graph` function, it creates a graph where every node is connected to every other node. I set `directed=false` so arrows don't show up when the graph is plotted. The `igraph` functions adds plotting of graphs to the `plot` function, so the newly created graph can be plotted as above. (It's easier than typing `plot.igraph`)

Comment: Thanks for accepting! Let me know if there's anything else I can do to improve my answer.