# Connecting every point to every point on a scatterplot

Tags: r, graph, line

I have a scatterplot of data and I want to connect every point to every point.  Everything I have found online only connects one point to the next point (such as, using type = "l").  Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using base plot to make your original scatterplot? Or are you using something like ggplot2?

Comment: Just using plot(x,..).@Dason

Comment: Think about your problem as of generating of a complete graph from vertices with coordinates. You can use the `igraph` package. Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434335/how-to-plot-a-complete-graph-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comment that indicated that the points are being plotted using `plot(x)` :

```
# define test data and plot it
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10) # test data
plot(x)

# add segments   
ix <- combn(length(x), 2)
segments(ix[1, ], x[ix[1, ]], ix[2, ], x[ix[2, ]])
```

[image: screnshot]

Comment: I like your use of `combn` much better than my `expand.grid`.